# Data migration in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have migration file called 220131208092530_add_active_to_outlet.rb. I have already done rake:db migrate RAILS_ENV=development. But I couldnt find 'active' field in my database.
I am using navicat.
Please help.

```
class AddActiveToOutlet < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
    add_column :outlets, :active, :boolean, null: false, default: true

    reversible do |dir|
        dir.up do
            Outlet.update_all(active: true)
        end
    end
end
```

end

Above is migration file code. What else do i have to do after rake db:migrate??

Comment: does the column appear in your `schema.rb` file?

Comment: Run rake db:migrate:status to know if you have actually run the migration or not. If you have, the status of migration should be 'up'. Add Outlet.reset_column_information in your migration file after add_column so all ActiveRecord caching is dropped